# Formulaic representation of time differential

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astronomy, time, time-dilation

It is a known fact that time passes at a different rate on earth than it does elsewhere in the universe. Where a second on earth passes uniformly, at an altitude of 11000 or also passes uniformly but at a slower rate on earth by approximately 3 billionths of a second per earth second.

Since we know that gravity is not linearly effective, it is most likely on a logarithmic scale meaning that time decelerates proportionately and equally to gravitational force.

To represent Relational Time Field, we use the Cyrillic symbol Ю. The notation differentiates between relative time and absolute time in its order of usage.

Since most scientific formulae were derived on earth, we can assume that their results are therefore relative to Earth's time field which is represented thus $ Earth_Ю$ but if we take absolute time as the measure, we need to account for Universal Time Field which would be $ Ю_{Earth} $.

To understand the problem, I need to solve how to build a comprehensive relationship between the two measures for conversion universally, of time and energy translation. There is ground theory proving this with Zero Point Energy.

Effectively, gravity is an equal yet opposite force to something else. If we use time distortion as that opposite force, how would we write this mathematically?
$ Ю_{Earth} \text {is not equal } Earth_{Ю}$

Consider the formula:
$$
v=\frac{s}{t}
$$
Velocity is relative to distance and time and distance is relative to velocity and time but, if time is variable then all calculations must therefore be relative to that variable.
Since $Earth_{Ю}$ is the basis of almost all calculations in the universe,  changing perception is akin to changing understanding. The catholic church once burnt scientists at the stake for daring to suggest that earth was not the centre of the solar system. In the same way, I am proving that Earth time is not the centre of time but a distortion field of it. This is why the Cyrillic Yu is being used to define Time as a physical component rather than a measure of an insubstantial concept. We live in a four dimensional universe but only recognise three of them. Yu defines the fourth dimension in absolute and relative terms and tips Einstein's self-absorbed theory over into absolute terms.

Am example of this is that time on the surface of a black hole passes so slowly that the ultra condensed energy we call matter is moving so slowly that we cannot see it. Time is so thick and dense that light is slowed down to the point where it travels below the escape velocity of the invisible star. We call that the event horizon. It is not gravity that is the issue but time itself.

Time density is ever so important to account that we miss its relevance and function in Energy transfer between mass and the equate of light relative to the applicable time field hence $ Ю_{Earth} \text {is not equal } Earth_{Ю}$ And therefore we need a formulaic representation of absolute time where $ Earth_{Ю}$ has a constant

Comment: This is physics rather than mathematics, but even for a physicist the use of symbols and terms is uncommon and confusing.

Comment: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_Time and the linked pages https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_Coordinate_Time and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocentric_Coordinate_Time

Comment: You may also be interested in this page about astronomical timekeeping https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26033/

Comment: This is not about time keeping at all, this is about fundamentally changing or perspective in the universe. Science is so fixated on general and special relativity that it fails to consider the possibility that time is the only fixed constant and everything else is relative to it. My question is whether we can establish a formulaic representation of this concept such as $$Ю_{E}=mc^{2Ю_{Earth}}$$ as the current understanding but the universal constant as $$Ю_{E}=mc^{2}$$?